# Entity Framework - NotSupportedException

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, notsupportedexception

```
var depts = ctx.Departments
            .OrderBy(d => d.deptName)
            .Select(d => d.deptNo);

foreach (int deptNumber in depts) {
    var deptReports = from d in ctx.Departments
                      join r in matchingIncidents on d.deptNo equals r.deptNo
                      where r.deptNo == deptNumber
                      select r;

    int deptReportsCount = deptReports.Count();
```

I am completely baffled! All the questions about this error say to use == on primitive fields (such as IDs), which I'm doing. Anything I do to this query generates the exception. The exact same code worked before and I don't know what I've done to it! Could someone please explain to me what's going on?

Also, I remember there being an EntityFramework class with methods that allowed you to convert objects within a query (e.g. dates), does anyone know what this class is?

UPDATE:

Here are the changes I made (it now works).

```
var deptReports = from r in matchingIncidents
                  join d in ctx.Departments on r.deptNo equals d.deptNo
                  where r.deptNo == deptNumber
                  select r;
```

Comment: Is `matchingIncidents` an `IQueryable` or a list of objects which are already loaded into memory? If it's an in-memory collection keep in mind that the `join` in your UPDATE code will not happen in the database but in memory - which means: The whole `Departments` table will be loaded into memory first before the join in executed in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matchingIncidents` looks like a local collection of a complex type (because you are using `r.deptNo`). That's not allowed in LINQ to Entities. You could try this instead:

```
foreach (int deptNumber in depts) {
    var deptReports = from d in ctx.Departments
                      join r in matchingIncidents.Select(m => m.deptNo)
                          on d.deptNo equals r
                      where r == deptNumber
                      select r;

int deptReportsCount = deptReports.Count();
```

`matchingIncidents.Select(m => m.deptNo)` is now a local collection of primitive types and `deptReports` is a sequence of `int` (assuming that `deptNo` is of type `int`). But for counting the resulting elements it should be still fine.

**Edit**

And you are probably searching for the static `EntityFunctions` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That's what I changed (trying to refactor/optimize my code). And you're bang on about the EntityFunctions class too! You're my hero :)

Comment: For anyone stuck on this issue, matchingIncidents is a list of Incident objects from a previous query.

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be:

```
join r in matchingIncidents on d.deptNo == r.deptNo
```

Comment: That's part of the join syntax. Taking it out results in a syntax  error.